# How do I display multi-lined scanner input in a text area- Java

Tags: java

Right so I have an algorithm (written in java) that runs a bash, or cmd if your using windows, script and then displays it in a text area in the gui which will be shown below. It works fine as in that it successfully gets the ifconfig info. However only one line of the data is shown. My question is how do I get it so that all the information is displayed in the text area. Thankyou in advance!

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.TextArea;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class This_Computer {

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void screen1() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    This_Computer window = new This_Computer();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public This_Computer() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        final TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
        textArea.setBounds(12, 43, 478, 389);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textArea);

        JButton btnConnectionProperties = new JButton("Connection Properties");
        btnConnectionProperties.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String[] cmdarray = {"ifconfig"};
                try {
                    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdarray);
                    Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner (process.getInputStream(), "IBM850");
                    scanner1.useDelimiter(" ");
                    String input = scanner1.nextLine ();
                    scanner1.close(); 
                    textArea.setText(input);

                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR");
                }
            }
        });
        btnConnectionProperties.setBounds(12, 12, 193, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnConnectionProperties);


    }
}
```

Comment: From what I can see, you only call scanner.nextline() once and there fore only read one line. You should keep building the String till there are no lines left. (Either concat one String object or use a StringBuilder for that, though dont forget to add a linebreak after each line!)

Comment: thanks for the advice, will give it a go

Answer (score 0):

As I didnt have enough time, I posted a quick comment, though I didnt provide any clear solution. So here is a way to solve your problem.

Instead of:

```
String input = scanner1.nextline();
//close scanner after reading one line
```

You could do this instead:

```
String ins = ""; // the String concatnation way
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); // The StringBuilder way
String temp;

while(scanner1.hasNextLine())
{
   temp = scanner1.nextLine() + "\n"; // Linebreaker for each line
   ins += temp;
   sb.append(temp);
}

// get String from StringBuilder
// StringBuilder.toString();
```

Note, that 2 ways are shown at the same time, you only need the StringBuilder the a String.

I hope this was usefull.